# Bokeh - updating source of renderer and DataTable - using Callback?

Tags: python, datatable, callback, bokeh

I recently picked up learning bokeh and I am completely lost making callbacks work.

What I would like to do is update the source using the PointDrawTool. It does update the plot and the table, but apparently it does not update the renderer or the source. This has me seriously confused and I'd appreciate some help.

What I have working is as follows:

```
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Circle
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook, Column, Row
from bokeh import events
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS

output_notebook()

p = figure(width = 400, height = 600)

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x': [38], 'y': [-12], 'color': ['red']
})

renderer = p.circle(x='x', y='y',
                    source=source,
                    color='color',
                    size=10)

columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
           TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
           TableColumn(field='color', title='color')]

table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200)

draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer],
                          empty_value='red')

p.add_tools(draw_tool)
p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

show(Row(p,table))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your method of rendering the chart (`show`) it isn't possible to update the source for the chart (unless you write custom JavaScript to do so). In order to achieve this you would need to use the Bokeh server, as described [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html).

Basically, put all your code in a file called 'main.py', and then save this in a folder with your project name. Then in the terminal run

```
bokeh serve --show project_name
```

I haven't used the PointDrawTool before, but if it's a widget, you'll also need to write functions to program how the source data should be updated, using the `on_click` or `on_change` methods described [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html).

Comment: Thanks. Using the Bokeh server does indeed update the source allowing me to use the on_change function.

    def on_change_data_source(attr, old, new):
        print('-- OLD DATA: {}'.format(old))
        print('-- NEW DATA: {}'.format(new))
        print('-- SOURCE DATA: {}'.format(source.data))

    source.on_change('data', on_change_data_source)

I still find it frustrating that source is not updated in the notebook. I will have to look further into that.

Comment: @strider you're welcome! Please mark my answer correct if it solved the problem :-)